# SVN: trunk, branches and tags

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, tags, branch, trunk

It's a month I'm trying to figure out the best solution to my problem and this is the best one. I would like to know if you agree with it.

We are developing a set of interconnected web applications. We treat each application as a single solution indipendent from the others. Each application is formed by different projects, but this doens't matter much.

We use to develop on the trunk new functionalities. Whenever we publish something live we tag the trunk version with a version name. For example suppose that the first trunk version is tagged 1.0.0. When we develop furhter implementation (i.e. we are working on 1.1.0) a series of bug comes out from the production version. What we are thinking to do is checkout tag 1.0.0 and correct bugs towards version 1.0.1.

Now what we would like to accomplish is to tag EACH revision version. In other words we would like to be able to have a perfect working copy of 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2 ...

Now this is my solution, I would like to know if you agree on it.

1. I checkout my tagged version 1.0.0 to the local /tags folder
2. I branch this version to /branches/1.0.1 repository folder
3. I checkout my new branch to the local /branches folder
4. I correct bugs on the branch 1.0.1
5. When, after x commits, everything is ok, I tag this new version to the /tags/1.0.1

and so on for each new bug / new release. I tried it and if I checkout the /tags folder i can see all the versions, perfectyl working.

Now when I'm ready with the 1.1.0 I should merge the last tag (or Branch, they should be the same at the end if everything is correct) on the trunk using "Merge a range of revisions" options. When everything is merged, I should have a fully working 1.1.0 version with the revisions corrected in the past. Compile, test and then publish and, obviously, tag it to /tags/1.1.0 folder on the server.

What do you think?
Thanks,
Marco

Comment: ever considered using a DVCS? with that much branching (and merging) and tagging going on they might be superior by a huge margin compared to SVN

Comment: I'm not sure moving to a DVCS would necessarily change anything here.  The branches/tags/trunk structure is standard in SVN.  Moving to a different system might move to a different paradigm, but not necessarily because of its being a distributed system vs. a centralized one.

Comment: @Andrew: +1 to that, I wonder where the "DVCS solves all problems" idea started, some things are just development strategies, and not tool related.

Comment: Hi knittl, sorry but I really don't know DVCS... Which advantages would I earn by using them? Thanks, Marco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally all development is done on trunk, and trunk is what you base releases off. You use branches either to stabilize the code in preparation for a release, to patch a release or to implement a feature that can't be developed on trunk for several reasons.

When using the branch for stabilization or to patch a release, the fix for the bug, or the changes that should go to the stabilization branch are all developed on trunk, and merged selectively to the branch.

When using a feature branch, you commit to the branch and then merge back to trunk (and maybe from there to stabilization/patch branches.

Short story, I miss trunk in your development cycle, and I wonder how you ensure that all changes are eventually in trunk, because that's where your next major feature release will/should start from.

Comment: Hi Sander, thanks for your interest in my question. Trunk is where we develop new functionalities, so is where we continue to work to reach the new minor or major version. If I understood well you are saying that if I fix a bug on the branch, as soon as I commit it, I should merge everything istantly. Why don't do that at the end? Is more secure to do that fix by fix? Thanks, Marco

Comment: I mean that if there's a bug in your code, it's probably also a bug in trunk. Therefor if you fix it on trunk first, you guarantee that new versions include a fix for the bug. After that you can prepare patches for releases etc. on the branches

Comment: I would disagree with fixing in trunk and cherrypick-merging "up" into the branch. Fixes should go to the stable branch first priority and can be merged "down" into the trunk without fear of selecting wrong changes for the merge. Very possible to define a general "checkin fixes here, merge down all changes to trunk" policy.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a pretty good process, except that your bug fixes on the production branches will, in all likelihood, need to be reflected in trunk as well.  Therefore, there shouldn't be a need to merge *everything* into trunk at the end because you will have already done it as you went.

Otherwise, it does seem that you are using branches and tags appropriately, so kudos on that.  I've seen far too many projects that could not identify in source control the current (or some other) production version (which, if you need to fix something or roll back, is essential).  There's no excuse for that, in my opinion.

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for your reply! Why do you say that there is no need to merge everything into trunk? How would I fix bugs on trunk if not through a merge? Thanks! Marco

Comment: @Marconline You merged as you went, not at the end.  When you fix a bug in a production release, in all likelihood, you have the same bug in trunk.  So, you would merge the bug from your production branch into trunk at that time.  When you get ready to release from trunk, you already have all the bug fixes from the development branches in trunk.  So, there is no need for another merge into trunk.

Comment: I think that is what Sander says... If I merge the LAST branch I should have the same behavior, am I wrong? Your solution is better maybe bacause I can develop on trunk with  bugs corrected in almost real time...

Comment: @Marconline You really should, as a matter of best practice, keep the trunk up to date with bug fixes as you go.  I notice that @Sander advocates doing the bug fixes in trunk and merging them into the relevant production branch.  This works fine also so long as the fix works exactly the same both places, but in real situations, I have found that I need to fix the production code first, then make sure the fix works in trunk.  So, I would implement my fix on the production branch, then merge to trunk.  Just my preference, though.

Answer (score 1):

What you described sounds like the normal procedure for tagging and branching to me. That's the way I use subversion, and it works very well.

Comment: Thanks tanges for your opinion. For you is normal, for me is quite new. It took me long time to understand the best way to operate on our projects. ;-) Glad to hear that works well for you. Thanks again, Marco

Answer (score 0):

Sounds good to me.

Depending on the ammount of fixes getting released I wouldn't bother with createting branches for every minor release. Creating those, communicating to people what to checkout/where to checkin, merging down etc. Rinse & repeat.

Having a branch for each major release and using that as a "maintenance"-branch works well for us.

here is a description of the process in case you are interested:
[svn deployment strategies for multiple groups of developers (not co-located) working on different components of the same project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3780824/svn-deployment-strategies-for-multiple-groups-of-developers-not-co-located-work/3824086#3824086)

Define policies for branches and create a new branch only if you have to do something that does not fit into current policies. Helps to limit the branching.